# Pass source xml file name as a parameter to the stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

As I have understood it there is no way to get XSLT 1.0 in a stylesheet to accept direct funtions like "base-uri()" or simliar and I have read about a method when you "pass source xml file name as a parameter to the stylesheet".

What does that exactly mean?

My situation is that I have a large number of XML-files and one stylesheet that I would like to use for all of these files.

In the head section, when XSLT transformed, I would really like to display the source xml filename (i.e. the file that invoked the stylesheet).

How could this be done in the simplest way?

Many thanks!

/Paul

Comment: Well which XSLT processor do you use, how do you use it (from the command line, using another programming language and the processor's API)? How you pass a parameter depends on the particular XSLT processor and its command line options or its API.

Comment: Martin, this is made as simple as possible. I have a handmade stylesheet made in "gedit" and all the processing is done by the browser. I have tried it out in Firefox, Google Chrome and IExplorer and the stylesheet works, so it's basically that way it should be done (if possible) - given that the future readers will only have browsers at their disposal.

Comment: Are you tying the XML to the stylesheet using a processing instruction in the XML file, such as `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mystyle.xsl"?>
`?

Comment: How is the processing "done in the browser"? Using Javascript? Or using `<?xml-stylesheet ...?>`? With Javascript you can set a parameter (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_XSLT_JavaScript_Interface_in_Gecko/Setting_Parameters), using `<?xml-stylesheet ...?>` you can't, other than in Mozilla browsers where is some restricted way https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/PI_Parameters.

Comment: Are you transforming the XML to HTML with `mystyle.xsl`?

Comment: Michael & Martin, yes I'm using  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mystyle.xsl"?> . Then I guess it can't be done in a simple way. Will it be very complicated to do it using Javascript? Or perhaps PHP?

Comment: How exactly does the user select the file to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XSLT transforms your XML input to HTML then in your HTML you can use Javascript to read out `window.location.href` respectively its components. The usual way to simply output something with client-side Javascript in a certain position would be `document.write`, but that is not supported in Gecko browsers in the HTML result of an XSLT transformation. You can however use DOM methods like `createTextNode` and `replaceChild` or `appendChild`, the following tries to do that and mimic the effect of document.write by replacing the `script` element with a text node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script>
      function outputUrl() {
      var currentScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var lastScript = currentScripts[currentScripts.length - 1];
        var fileUrl = window.location.href;
        var steps = fileUrl.split('/');
        var fileName = steps[steps.length - 1];
        lastScript.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(fileName), lastScript);
      }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <section>
        <h2>File : <script>outputUrl();</script></h2>
      </section>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footer">
  <section>
    <h2>Footer of file : <script>outputUrl();</script></h2>
  </section>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In an online test http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015071502.xml with current versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE (on Windows 8.1) that way the file name show up in the right places but I have not tested that approach when more `script` elements are present with `src` attributes or `defer` or `async`. But you could always make sure you put a `<span id="fileName"></span>` where you need the file name and then use `document.getElementById('fileName').textContent = fileName;`, that way the output does not depend on the perhaps brittle approach of hoping that the `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` collection has the current `script` as it last item.

Comment: Martin, I just tried it out briefly and it seems to do exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing this. Now I have to bring this together with my existing stylesheet to combine them to something useful. Great!!